# How to get total of parents categories?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, the first is the following

```
"Categories"

id    name         parent_id

1     Food         NULL
2     Vegetable     1
3     Fruit         1
4     Tomatoes      2
5     onion         2
6     bananas       3
7     grapes        3
```

the second table is the following

```
"amounts"
id     amount      category_id
1      100         4
2      50          6
3      25          5
4      100         7
5      50          4
6      25          7
```

> Currently categories table are three levels and I want to return all
>   the Categories along with total columns:
>
> Means that  sum of the category of level 2 is the total of level 3 and
>   the total of  level 2 should was the sum of level 1. I would really
>   appreciate some help Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

Comment: Thank you but is different.